# get label of an index in pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
                   c1     c2  
name       sample
person1    a1      aaa    AAA  
           b1      bbb    BBB  
           c1      ccc    CCC  
person2    d1      ...
```

I want to iterate through the dataframe, one person at a time, and check if values in columns match a criteria. If I get a match, then I'd like to extract the label for that index (at level[1] and as a string), and create a set of all such indices. So say my criteria is that column_value == bbb, then I'd like to get "b1"

The following produces almost what I want, but it returns of set of generator objects, rather than the names of the labels as strings.

```
index_set = set()
for person, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
    idx = new_df.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
    index_set.add(x for x in idx)
```

which produces something like  at 0x0000022F6F05D200>,  at 0x0000022F6F05D410>,....

So how to make it produce something like {"b1", "f1", "h1",...} instead?

And another question: when iterating through df by creating new_df the index names don't seem to transfer to new_df. Can this be avoided somehow? It would make the code more readable if I could refer to the index as get_level_values('sample') rather than get_level_values(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add` method of a set adds one element, in your case it adds an iterator. You could use list comprehension to add a few: `[index_set.add(x) for x in idx]`, but the correct way is to use `update` method:

```
index_set.update(idx)
```